What were other physicists' opinions on David Bohm's book "Quantum Theory"
Shortly before coming up with his pilot-wave theory, David Bohm published a book on nonrelativistic quantum mechanics titled Quantum Theory. In it dedicates large sections of the book on quantum measurement and its philosophy, largely from a perspective somewhat between orthodox QM and Bohr's Copenhagen interpretation.
I was wondering about contemporary opinions on the book, maybe even reviews. Are the philosophical sections sound? Does it accurately represent Bohr's (or Heisenberg's, or any other 'Copenhagen Interpretation' proponents') opinions? Did Bohr himself ever comment on it? Etc.

From Bohm's letter to Schatzman on September 7, 1952: "I was a strong “Bohrian” and wrote my book under the assumption (later proved wrong) that the principle of Complementarity was a materialist point of view. It certainly is very dialectical, but I did not see at that time that it is not materialist. After writing my book, I sent a copy to Einstein. He called me up asking to discuss the book, especially the Section on the paradox of EPR, which he liked very much. He thought I gave Bohr’s point of view the most convincingly possible presentation, but he still refused to accept it."

The book is well cited for introducing a version of the Einstein-Podolsky–Rosen (EPR) paradox using the electron spin projections along different axes of space instead of the original position and momentum.
I do not know if the book is philosophical but it is known for containing a balance of text and equations, in contrast with the more mathematical books of Dirac and von Neumann.
Reception of the book
For an early review on the book itself, see D. R. Inglis, Am. J. Phys. review (1952), doi:10.1119/1.1933314. The reviewer considers it a clear textbook for students and compares it with Leonard I. Schiff's Quantum Mechanics, saying that Bohm's book is an introduction for that book as Schiff's book discusses relativistic quantum mechanics more. Nothing about the philosophy part is pointed out.
The book was written one year before the publication of Bohm's paper on Bohmian mechanics, so it was written as a textbook on the Copenhagen view. Famous philosopher of science, Karl Popper writes:

There is David Bohm who published in 1951 a textbook, Quantum Theory, which was not only orthodox in the Copenhagen sense but one of the clearest and fullest, most penetrating and critical presentations of the Copenhagen point of view ever published.

From the introduction of K. Popper, Quantum Theory and the Schism in Physics (written about 1956 but published as a book in 1982).
Finally in an obituary, physicist N. David Mermin is cited saying:

There was a time when that was probably the best of the available textbooks about quantum mechanics, which lies at the heart of contemporary physics. It is the theory of matter at the atomic and subatomic levels, and it is notorious for being philosophically obscure.

From E. Pace, David J. Bohm, 74, Physicist and Writer On Quantum Theory, The New York Times (1992). Interestingly Mermin does say that it had a lot of "obscure" philosophy.
Criticism
All criticism I could find about Bohm was mostly based on his 1952 Bohmian mechanics and not on his book.
Jeremy Bernstein, says something about Eugene Wigner criticism:

Abner Shimony, who was then a
student of Wigner, asked Wigner what he thought of the book. He
told Shimony he thought that it was a good book but that there was
too much “schmoozing.” He then asked Shimony if he knew what
schmoozing was. In my case, and probably Shimony’s, it was just
the schmoozing that attracted us to the book.

From Berstein, "More about Bohm’s quantum", Am. J. Phys (2011), doi:10.1119/1.3556713 Shimony went up to co-author the CHSH inequality (a kind of Bell's inequality tested in Aspect's experiments), however this discussion of Wigner was probably in the 1960s much after the publication and debates on Bohmian mechanics.
Bohm's own description of the book
Bohm said in a letter that his textbook was

a clear presentation of Bohr’s point of view (the first clear, if I may boast a little).

from the letter to Miriam Yevick; Letter 66, Folder C117, January 23, 1952 (extracted from F. Del Santo & G. C. Krizek, 'Against the "nightmare of a mechanically determined universe": Why Bohm was never a Bohmian' 2023).
In an interview with Nobel laureate in Biology Maurice Wilkins, Bohm also mentions a review of his book:

Yes. There was one review which pointed out that I was weaving the physics and the mathematics together, which this fellow liked. In other words, not everybody in the physics community was happy about this emphasis on mathematics. There were a lot of people who felt pushed out.

From "Interview of David Bohm by Maurice Wilkins", session III, 1986 July 7,
Niels Bohr Library & Archives, American Institute of Physics.
In his interview, Wilkin asks if the book was widely used, Bohm says:

It was used in quite a few places. Also, I sent the book to various physicists including Pavvy [?] and Deborwy [?] and Einstein and Bohr. I got a very enthusiastic answer from Pavvy who liked the way I was weaving the physics and the mathematics together and also raising philosophical questions. Bohr didn’t answer; I don’t know why. Some people told me later he had so much stuff coming on he never read it. Now, Einstein liked the book very much and wanted to discuss it with me. We’ll come to that later. I got comments from other people but afterwards, it was adopted in a number of universities, a fair number. Some people didn’t like it, they wanted more mathematics. But there’s a fair number who did like it.

The badly transcripted names above are clearly Pauli and de Broglie. Bohm mentions Einstein because it was Einstein who recommended Bohm to dig deeper into quantum theory after having read his book (leading to Bohmiam mechanics).
Other
Interestingly, Hugh Everett the creator of the many-worlds interpretation was a reader of Bohm's textbook (that he studied in Princeton University), see for example Everett "The Theory Of The Universal Wave Function" (1956).

At an informal level, I can attest that Feynman liked this book.

@CosmasZachos is your comment a reference to some specific work by Feynman?

No; private communication: I was his TA. He liked Bohm.
